# How to allow spark to ignore missing input files?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I want to run a spark job (spark v1.5.1) over some generated S3 paths containing avro files. I'm loading them with:

```
val avros = paths.map(p => sqlContext.read.avro(p))
```

Some of the paths will not exist though. How can I get spark to ignore those empty paths? Previously I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783926/bypassing-org-apache-hadoop-mapred-invalidinputexception-input-pattern-s3n), but I'm not sure how to use that with the new dataframe API.

Note: I'm ideally looking for a similar approach to the linked answer that just makes input paths optional. I don't particularly want to have to explicitly check for the existence of paths in S3 (since that's cumbersome and may make development awkward), but I guess that's my fallback if there's no clean way to implement this now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would use the scala `Try` type in order to handle the possibility of failure when reading a directory of avro files. With 'Try' we can make the possibility of failure explicit in our code, and handle it in a functional manner:

```scala
object Main extends App {

  import scala.util.{Success, Try}
  import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
  import com.databricks.spark.avro._

  val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("example"))
  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

  //the first path exists, the second one doesn't
  val paths = List("/data/1", "/data/2")

  //Wrap the attempt to read the paths in a Try, then use collect to filter
  //and map with a single partial function.
  val avros =
    paths
      .map(p => Try(sqlContext.read.avro(p)))
      .collect{
        case Success(df) => df
      }
  //Do whatever you want with your list of dataframes
  avros.foreach{ df =>
    println(df.collect())
  }
  sc.stop()
}
```

Comment: From the spark docs: `collect()` can cause the driver to run out of memory, though, because `collect()` fetches the entire RDD to a single machine. Is there a solution without using `collect()`? This is for a very large dataset.

Comment: That is true when `collect()` is called on an RDD. Where I call `collect(...)` the first time, containing a partial function, it is on a list of RDDs, it is the collect function on the List, not on any RDD. This is equivalent to doing a `map` and a `filter`. I do use `collect()` again at the end inside the `foreach` at the end but that's just an example of operating the list of RDDs, I don't expect that is what you would do in your own application, but I needed a simple ending to see that the approach had worked correctly.

Comment: Oh OK. I'll give it a try and see if it works then. I thought the first `collect` was evaluating the RDDs and sending all the data to the driver node.

Comment: This is a pretty perfect answer, definitely deserves the bounty